# Two different 5V rails connected in parallel

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

First of all, I know that connecting two non-ideal voltage sources with same values in parallel is not a good idea (according to my research so far).

If you look at the schematic below, you can see that the two power sources, both 5V, one from the main power rail and the other from the USB port(from a PC) are connected in parallel to the VCC of the chip.

1: What happens if both the sources are connected at the same time? Does not that contradict about two sources connected in parallel with each other is dangerous theory?

2: If both sources do not sink current and only source current, does that make any difference in the implementation below?

3: Does the implementation of the diode makes any difference in this particular scenario?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The circuit shows how one device may be powered from two different supplies without one supply "forcing" current into the other. This is useful to allow graceful failover of one supply, e.g. a dead battery, while the other is still working.

The purpose of the two diodes is to separate the supplies *from each other*. Why is that needed? Consider if one supply is a Li-ion battery and the other from the mains... continual charging could cause the battery to fail, perhaps with a *bang*. Or, though both are nominally 5.00 V, what if one supply is actually at 5.01 volts, and the other at 4.99 V -- the regulator on the 4.99 V supply would be fighting to drop the voltage while that on the 5.01 V supply is raising it!

However, the supplies will not actually split current between them to power the circuit, because one with slightly higher output will provide most or all the current.

BTW, note that the UART socket is shown connected to *chassis* ground, while the +5 VDC input capacitor is shown connected to *earth* ground... Are they connected??

Comment: Suppose the schottky diodes forward bias at 0.3V.  If the 2 supplies are less than 0.3V apart, then both diodes will be forward biased and some current will flow through both.  If we're going to say that most of the current flows through one diode, we should add that that occurs if there is more than 0.3V difference between them.

Comment: @scorpdaddy, True, and the current/voltage relationship is nonlinear: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/i-v-characteristic-curves.html , so the "sharing" drops off rather abruptly. To simplify, "most or all the current", q.v.